# Import java class to Jsp in Maven project

Tags: maven, jsp

I have a project in IDE, so I made a new project in Maven. I copy all the files and classes, and I fill the pom.xml.

This is OK, but the problem is in JSP,eclipse dont find the imported clases.

```
<%@page import="modelos.Mascota"%>
```

This import for example cant be resolved. 
What I'm doing wrong?

All my java classes are in:

```
\src\main\resources
```

And jsp files in:

```
src\main\webapp
```

Comment: can you upload your project anywhere ?

Comment: Hi! I'm running the project in local. I didn't buy a server yet

Comment: I want you to upload project in github or gitlab or anywhere else

Comment: Have you uploaded project to github ?

Comment: No, I finally solved changing the class to  \src\main\java. And I'm still working in local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .java files must be in

\src\main\java

Answer (score 0):

check your dependencies for the class whether it is exist or not

```
modelos.Mascota
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. My dependencies for the class? Do you refer to add the packets and class in pom.xml?

Comment: check your dependencies for the class whether it is exist or not

modelos.Mascota

Comment: just you have to confirm that class is exist or not and class path too

Comment: Yes this exist. This is the complete path: src/main/java/modelos/Mascota.java  Is this what you refer?